# Segmentation fault when trying to access pointer in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to access a pointer inside of a struct, I tried placing * in front of the struct pointer
to access the pointer inside the struct, but it segfaults.

code segfaults on `*ptr->numberOfClients = clients;`

```
int getNumberOfClients(struct fuzzerObj *ptr)
{
    int rtrn;
    long clients;
    char *input;
    char *holder = NULL;

    printf(BOLDBLUE"How many clients will you be connecting to this fuzz server?\n"RESET);
    printf(BOLDBLUE"---> "RESET);
    rtrn = getUserInput(&input);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        errorHandler("Can't Get User input\n", FUNCTION_ID_GET_NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS);
        return -1;
    }
    if (strlen(input))         
    {
         clients = strtol(input, &holder, 10);
         if (input == holder)
         {
             errorHandler("invalid long conversion\n", FUNCTION_ID_GET_NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS);
             return -1;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        errorHandler("No Value To Compute\n", FUNCTION_ID_GET_NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS);
        return -1;
    }
    *ptr->numberOfClients = clients;

    free(input);
    return 0;
}

int getUserInput(char **buf)
{
    int i = 0, max = 1024, c;
    *buf = reallocarray(NULL, 1025, sizeof(char *));
    if(*buf == NULL)
    {
        errorHandler("Mem Error\n", FUNCTION_ID_GET_USER_INPUT);
        free(*buf);
        return -1;
    }
    while (true) { // skip leading whitespace
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) break; // end of file
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true) {
        c = getchar();
        if (isspace(c) || c == EOF) // at end, add terminating zero
            buf[i] = 0;
        break;
    }
    *buf[i] = c;
    if (i==max-1) { // buffer full
        max = max+max;
        *buf = (char*)realloc(*buf,max); // get a new and larger buffer
        if (buf == 0)
        {
            errorHandler("Realloc Error\n", FUNCTION_ID_GET_USER_INPUT);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    i++;
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the struct

```
struct fuzzerObj
{
    int parserResponse;
    int *numberOfClients;
    int *clientFuzzerType[1024];
    int *clientSockets[1024];
    int *clientApplication[1024];
    int *clientFuzzer[1024];
    int *connectedClients;
    int *socket;
    int *fuzzer;
    int *application;
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
};
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use the debugger. Also, compile with all warnings and debug info. So on Linux, compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and use `gdb`

Comment: i did compile with -Wall -Werror, and gdb backtrace said Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 806c06400 (LWP 100709/fuzzer)]
0x000000000040a07f in getNumberOfClients (ptr=0x806c57000)
    at libBlackBoxUI.c:62
62     *ptr->numberOfClients = clients;

Comment: So learn a few more commands of `gdb` and use it cleverly to understand more. Correct your source code a little bit. Repeat till you are happy.

Comment: when i wasn't using pointers the value would be become zero after passing the struct to another function, i assumed i needed to use pointers, like if you pass an int to a function they each get a copy, but i wanted the value to be shared so i made it a pointer.

Comment: I forgot to malloc memory for numberOfClients i believe that is it.

Comment: If you are on Linux, then [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a useful tool (for [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) bugs).

Comment: Why is `numberOfClients` a pointer and not a simple `int` stored directly in the structure?  Using `int` instead of `int *` will save 8 bytes per structure (plus the overhead for a memory allocation) on the typical 64-bit system (nothing on a 32-bit system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major problem that I see (unless you've not shown it in your code snippets).  `numberOfClients` is declared as such:

```
struct fuzzerObj
{
    ...
    int *numberOfClients;
    ...
};
```

Before you assign an `int` to it.  You must assign memory to store the `int`:

1.

```
    ptr->numberOfClients = malloc(sizeof(*(ptr->numberOfClients)));
    *(ptr->numberOfClients) = clients;
    ...
    free(ptr->numberOfClients);
```

2.

```
    int temp;
    ptr->numberOfClients = &temp;
    *(ptr->numberOfClients) = clients;
    ...
    // Write to a file here???
```

Another question... why are the fields of `fuzzerObj` pointers?  If you make them `int`s instead of pointers to `int`s, you wouldn't have the difficulties you're experiencing.

**EDIT**

The second method shown above is not safe because once the function that has declared `temp` `return`s, `temp` no longer exists, and therefore `numberOfClients` doesn't have valid memory, and should not be used.

Comment: i was using int's before, but after setting the variables they became 0 after passing the value to another function, so I thought i had to use pointers so each function does not get there own copy.

Comment: @2trill2spill If if you pass `struct fuzzerObj *ptr` from function to function, the field values should not change unless it's happening programmatically (hopefully not due to a bug!).

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, time to go find that bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally unclear why data member numberOfClients defined as a pointer instead of to be an object of type int

```
int *numberOfClients;
```

Try the following

```
ptr->numberOfClients = ( int * )malloc( sizeof( int ) );
if ( ptr->numberOfClients ) *ptr->numberOfClients = clients;
```

Also take into account that variable clients is defined as

```
long clients;
```

In some implementations sizeof( lomg ) can be greater than sizeof( int ).

It is in general a bad design. It is unclear whether data members of the structures were initialized and corresponding memory were allocated.